# SOT23 marking code SPR4

Tags: voltage-regulator

My search for the SPR4 lands me here but couldn't find a definitive answer. I'm leaning towards SP but that is pointing me to BSS84. The designation on the board is "Uxx" while others are 'Qxx". Thank you

[image: SPR4 SOT23-3]

Comment: What does it look like if you turn the device off and probe it with DMM in diode mode?

Comment: Getting some odd readings while in a circuit. The 5V reg feeds the Vin and Vout tied to the CTL pin of F10 (I am guessing MIC2514) which provides the 5V supply to the onboard chips. The same has a marking code of "SPRY" on other PCB if that matters. Thank you.

Comment: I'll bet it's a chinese part, those kind of fly under the radar. This is the only thing I could find, don't know if it helps; https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fclub.1688.com%2Farticle%2F31945632.htm

Comment: If it were a vreg, the voltage would not be the same on both sides. I'd pull it off the board measure it. I'll bet it's a diode

Comment: I was leaning towards MCP1700-5002E/TT LDO v. reg but what baffles me is like what you said, the voltage is the same on both sides. My Fluke DVM confirmed Vout=5 volts at no load. I would expect a lower Vout if it is a diode. Guessed no choice but to remove it or cut the trace and test. Thank you

Comment: Solved. It's like searching for a needle in a haystack but it pays off. I bench tested and it's confirmed. https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MAX809S-D.PDF